# i want to design three layer with tableview. can anyone explain

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to design three layers with tableview. can anyone explain

```
if indexPath.section == 0 {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HederCell") as? HederCell
        cell?.textLabel?.text = getData?.mainservice_name
        return cell!
    }
```

I have tried to make this type not getting properly
please check below image for better understanding my question.

[image: sample]

Comment: what is not happening. please clarify a bit more

Comment: i have three type layer 1. category type this is show on first like (Hair) and than come 2. mainList it will be come in category the mailList data show under (Hair)->(Hair wash) than  3. is service list. (Hair Treatment) . now tell me how cam manage this.

Answer (score 0):

if you want some text before table view cell please use this overridden method and design your cell accordingly by using UIview.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) you have a header view Hair and Body

2) You have two tableviewcell.

i)

which you will use for hair wash(1) together with hair treatment for section 1

&

body care (3) together with body care for section 2

ii) which you will use for hand and foot care and massage services and others